# How to save / load dynamically created components using Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-dynamic-components

I want to make site like Linkedin blog.

I could create dynamic component like this.
but when I reload browser, dynamically created component is gone.

How can I cache dynamically created component to localStorage??
and How can I load dynamically component from localStorage when I reload browser ??

and one more question.
Do I need ngOnDestroy() in this code?

I added localStorage part like this. but "Converting circular structure to JSON at JSON.stringify" TypeError occurred.

What is the best solution to cache array of ComponentRef objects??

⬇︎This is parent component

```
// I added this part
import { COMPONENTS_REFERENCES } from '../../constants';

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

    index: number;
    componentsReferences = [];

    @ViewChild('viewContainerRef', { read: ViewContainerRef }) VCR: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(
        private CFR: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        // I added this part.
        const cachedComponents = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(COMPONENTS_REFERENCES));
        if (cachedComponents && cachedComponents.length > 0) {
            this.componentsReferences = cachedComponents;
        }

        this.index = 1;
    }

    addChild() {
        const componentFactory = this.CFR.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);
        const componentRef: ComponentRef<ChildComponent> = this.VCR.createComponent(componentFactory);
        const currentComponent = componentRef.instance;
        currentComponent.selfRef = currentComponent;
        currentComponent.index = this.index++;
        currentComponent.userId = this.user.id;
        currentComponent.compInteraction = this;
        this.componentsReferences.push(componentRef);  

        // I added this part
        localStorage.setItem(COMPONENTS_REFERENCES, JSON.stringify(this.componentsReferences));
    }

    removeChild(index: number) {
        if (this.VCR.length < 1) {
            return;
        }
        const componentRef = this.componentsReferences.filter(x => x.instance.index === index)[0];
        const component: ChildComponent = <ChildComponent>componentRef.instance;
        const vcrIndex: number = this.VCR.indexOf(componentRef);
        this.VCR.remove(vcrIndex);
        this.componentsReferences = this.componentsReferences.filter(x => x.instance.index !== index);

        // I added this part
        localStorage.setItem(COMPONENTS_REFERENCES, JSON.stringify(this.componentsReferences));
    }

    // ... and another ChildComponent add/remove method here
}
```

⬇︎This is HTML of Parent component

```
<div>
    <ng-template #viewContainerRef></ng-template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `listObject` in your parent component and cache your `listObject`  to `localStorage`, you can get it and use it when you load your browser.

your key would be post_cache and value would be array of json object (array of posts)

PS: I dont see anything in your code which is needed to be destroyed

Comment: thank you for your helpful advice. I fixed my code. I thought to cache componentsReferences array to localStorage. But this code become error( ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON at JSON.stringify).

Comment: yes It causes recursion, thus serialization error. If you feel that this answer is helpfull please consider to upvote and/or mark it as answer. Regards